# How to change the data of a particular column and multiply them depending upon the specific values in another column using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I want to select the year '2019/0'(string) from the column 'year of entry' and only multiply their 'grades' times 2 which is in another column

| year of entry | Grades |
| --- | --- |
| 2019/0 | 14 |
| 2010/0 | 21 |
| 2019/0 | 15 |

this is what I have tried so far:

```
df.loc[df("Year of Entry"),'2018/9'] = df("Grades")*2
```

its been giving me an error and im not sure if this is the right method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
df.loc[df['year of entry'].eq('2019/0'), 'Grades'] *= 2
```

*NB. the modification is **in place**.*

modified `df`:

```
  year of entry  Grades
0        2019/0      28
1        2010/0      21
2        2019/0      30
```

Comment: thank you but this still shows me an error:

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:1773: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

any idea?

Comment: This means you have a prior incorrect slicing, what did you do before to generate `df`?

Comment: it was 'dataset' before I changed it to 'df'.
should I use 'dataset' instead?

Comment: How did you change it? Can you provide the full code in your question?